# application force closed when exited Android

Tags: android, duration, forceclose, android-music-player

My music player application seems to have a problem. When I exit from it, it pops out force close warning. This is the part of the code where I think might be the cause of the problem after debugging it:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
               long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

               // Displaying Total Duration time
               songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
               // Displaying time completed playing
               songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

               // Updating progress bar
               int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
               //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
               songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

               // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
           }
        };
```

And here's the logcat:

```
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.example.musicshare.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity$1.run(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:341)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-13 13:26:01.700: E/AndroidRuntime(31838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is with mp.getDuration I think but I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your runnable task still runs at the back even after you exit. So my gues is that you could have forgot to call the `removeCallbacks()`.

My suggestion is to add the below line in your `onBackPressed()` or at the place where you exit the app,

```
 mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

Make sure you declare your Runnable mUpdateTimeTask globally so that it is available through out your code.

Answer (score 0):

Should remove callback before postRunnable

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
mHandler.post(...);
```